# Owncloud: Log-Files for login-attempts

Tags: security, splunk, owncloud

Does Owncloud log any files with successfull/failed login attempts? I would like to transfer these into Splunk to anaylze potential attacks against our system. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should checkout the [App](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3398) and [Add-On](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3397) for [Nextcloud](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/apps/#/search/nextcloud) on [Splunkbase](https://splunkbase.splunk.com):

- [App for Nextcloud](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3398)
- [Add-On for Nextcloud](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3397)

From the Splunkbase [page](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/3398/#/details):

> - Successful and failed logins and ratio of the same

Installation docs: https://intranet.graabek.com/cloud/index.php/s/Lc9oXkaWNmQHBqG#pdfviewer

Splunk Pro Tip™: check Splunkbase to see if your data source of choice already has an app/add-on available :)

Answer (score -1):

You can generate a log file in Owncloud by following the steps at https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/troubleshooting/providing_logs_and_config_files.html . However, this is most likely going to be formatted for human use, not for processing by Splunk.

I suggest you look at the syslog logging option described at https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/configuration/server/logging/logging_configuration.html and send that syslog data to splunk. You can configure Splunk for syslog listening at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/Monitornetworkports

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this out!